# XmlNamespaceManager provided, but still get "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

i am trying to read the following and select a node in it

```
<ns1:OrderInfo xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxxx Some URL XXXX">
   <pricing someAttrHere>
      <childnodes>
   </pricing>
</ns1:OrderInfo>
```

.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(Server.MapPath("order.xml"));

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://xxxxxx Some URL XXXX");
query = "/ns1:OrderInfo/pricing";
XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes(query);
```

but it always give "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed"

as you can see above i add namespace using XmlNamespaceManager and still give the error
please any help

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to *use* your XmlNamespaceManager as well:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes(query, manager);
```

Comment: Oh man... How did I miss that?  Oh, I know how.  Microsoft's error messages really suxors.

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but you saved my day, thanks!