# xpath filter while parent node changes name

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I am trying to get the value of a node from third party source.  Part of the Xmlstructure has a node whose name changes between, point and framedPoint.  how do I get the latitude value??  here is part of the xml, their are many levels to the xml so have shown the relevant area.

here node is called point

```
 <tpegpointLocation xsi:type="TPEGSimplePoint">
     <point xsi:type="TPEGJunction">
         <pointCoordinates>
            <latitude>54.894825</latitude>
         </pointCoordinates>
     </point>
 </tpegpointLocation>
```

here framedPoint

```
<tpegpointLocation xsi:type="TPEGSimplePoint">
    <framedPoint xsi:type="TPEGJunction">
            <pointCoordinates>
                  <latitude>54.894825</latitude>
            </pointCoordinates>
    </framedPoint>
</tpegpointLocation>
```

Thanks, for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could use asterisk as a wildcard in your xpath

```
/tpegpointLocation/*/pointCoordinates/latitude
```

Comment: didnt realise that at the * node, a nod call "to" exists and that has the same structure.  It doesn't seem possible to use mix the wild card with point ie *oint?

Comment: No in this way; but you could use `*[ends-with(name(),'oint')]`

Comment: should have mentioned that the xml has a namespace, so my xpath each node looks like /x:latitude, .net now erroring and asking for XsltContext is needed??

Comment: I don't know .net in much detail but it seems to be necessary to define appropriate prefix? Might be following could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311526/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath would do the job:

```
//tpegpointLocation//pointCoordinates/latitude
```

Which means:

- `//tpegpointLocation` search for all `<tpegpointLocation>` elements in the XML file
- The second `//pointCoordinates` means search for all `<pointCoordinates>` elements below `<tpegpointLocation>` regardless which elements are between them (one or more or different names
- `/latitude` means get the `<latitude>` element below `<pointCoordinates>`

Please note that using `//` scans whole XML file. If you are able to change `//tpegpointLocation` it would be better and faster.