# Xml path that have multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I can't figure out what namespaces need to be used for following Xml (sample):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <ResponseCharge xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ResponseInfo xmlns="http://www.example.net">
            <ResponseDetail>
              <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>
              <RequestIdentifier>1029034</RequestIdentifier>
              <RetrievalReferenceNumber>634716660366</RetrievalReferenceNumber>
              <ProcessingTime>00:03:314</ProcessingTime>
            </ResponseDetail>
            <ResponseTransactionDetail>
              <AVSResponseCode />
              <CVVResponseCode />
              <AuthorizationSourceCode />
              <AuthorizationNumber>004454</AuthorizationNumber>
            </ResponseTransactionDetail>
            <EMVResponseData />
          </ResponseInfo>
        </ResponseCharge>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

My code looks like this atm:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(responseXmlFile);
            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            //nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            //nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            //nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.example.net");
            // getting NULL here
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/s:Envelope/s:Body/ResponseCharge/ResponseInfo/ResponseTransactionDetail/AuthorizationNumber", nsmgr);
```

I'm following this post: [Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311526/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed)

Comment: No namespace prefix on ResponseInfo in the XPath expression?

Comment: Getting NULL for my 'XmlNode' query.

Comment: I remove commented 'ResponseInfo'. Also changed XmlNode to XmlNodeList as in the link I follow.

Comment: Looks like there is no namespace for element ResponseCharge. I suggest  declaring a prefix for 'http://www.example.net' and using it in your query for nodes below ResponseCharge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace in your query for the elements in the `http://www.example.net/` namespace.

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ex", "http://www.example.net");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/s:Envelope/s:Body/ResponseCharge/ex:ResponseInfo/ex:ResponseTransactionDetail/ex:AuthorizationNumber", 
    nsmgr);
```

I've arbitrarily picked `ex` as the prefix here. What's defined in the `XmlNamespaceManager` only relates to your XPath query, the prefixes used in the document aren't relevant.

Alternatively, I'd suggest you use LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.net"

var doc = XDocument.Load(responseXmlFile);

var authNo = (int)doc.Descendants(ns + "AuthorizationNumber").Single();
```

Comment: This is in 95% correct answer. There is actually no need for 'ex' prefix for 'ResponseCharge'. Wasted almost all morning for this. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jakubee d'oh. That's what I get for not testing it... have fixed.