# Getting child nodes in XML with custom Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have a rather large XML file from a computer diagnostics session, and my goal is to grab the test results data and pump it into a PDF for the customer.  I've very little experience with XML and this is turning out to be a huge problem.

Here is a sample of the Document:

```
<pcd:DiagLog xmlns="http://www.pc-doctor.com/2004/8/diagLogger"
             xmlns:pcd="http://www.pc-doctor.com/2004/8/diagLogger"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pc-doctor.com/2004/8/diagLogger 
             http://www.pc-doctor.com/2004/8/diagLogger/diagLogger.xsd">
    <Application>
        <version>6.0.6818.10</version>
        <Start>
            <Time hour="04" minute="14" second="01" millisecond="34" month="10" day="15" year="2016" utcOffset="-480">2016-10-15T04:14:01.034-08:00</Time>
        </Start>
        <OS>Windows 10 Service Pack 0 PE x86 32-bit</OS>
    </Application>
       .......
    <DiagInfo>
      ....
        <TestResult EnglishResult="PASS">
                ....
        </TestResult>
    </DiagInfo>
```

There are thousands of lines between `</Application>` and `<DiagInfo>`, but I'm only concerned with the information found in `<DiagInfo>` and `<TestResult>`.

I thought I could grab the Nodes by simply:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("pcd", "http://www.pc-doctor.com/2004/8/diagLogger");
    XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/pcd:DiagLog/DiagInfo", manager);
```

But this is returning an empty list.  When I refer to [Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311526/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed), it **appears** I'm doing it right, but I don't think I'm understanding adding a namespace correctly.  When I change the Root Element to just: `<Diagnostics></Diagnostics>` instead of the `<pcd:DiagLog>`, and try: `doc.SelectNodes("/Diagnostics/DiagInfo", manager);` my nodes list is populated.

Can anyone see where I'm screwing up the Namespace?

Comment: @Tomalak that was an error from copy/paste.  I checked the code and the URIs match..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the namespace prefix for all nodes in that namespace.

This is incorrect: `/pcd:DiagLog/DiagInfo`.

This is correct: `/pcd:DiagLog/pcd:DiagInfo`.

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  I can't mark as the answer yet, but that worked.

Comment: Default namespace propagate. Explicit namespaces do not. Your XML uses a default namespace. Strictly speaking, if no node in your input XML uses the `pcd` prefix, you can throw out that namespace declaration with no ill effects. You are also not required to call that namespace `pcd` in C#. You can give it any handle you want, only the URIs need to match.