# Getting error on attribute selection

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML code

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata' xmlns:diffgr='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' FID='004'>
<Data>
   <users name='peter' UID='10003' diffgr:hasChanges='modified'/>
</Data>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I can get the name attribute by doing:

```
SelectSingleNode("/*/Data/*/@name");
```

and then print the value of that name.
But I want the value of the attribute `diffgr:hasChanges`

I tried to do similar

```
SelectSingleNode("/*/Data/*/@diffgr:hasChanges");
```

But when trying to print the value, I get error saying

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
  at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.get_QueryTree () <0x41689000 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr, System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator context) <0x41688e20 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr) <0x41688df0 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr) <0x41688d70 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select (System.String xpath) <0x41684000 + 0x00026> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes (System.String xpath) <0x416839a0 + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode (System.String xpath) <0x41683950 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at isoTopix.MyTest.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00018] in /home/tito/isoTopixSecurity/isoCode/console/tito.cs:28 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
  at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.get_QueryTree () <0x41689000 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr, System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator context) <0x41688e20 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr) <0x41688df0 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select (System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression expr) <0x41688d70 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select (System.String xpath) <0x41684000 + 0x00026> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes (System.String xpath) <0x416839a0 + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode (System.String xpath) <0x41683950 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0
```

I guess I need some escaping cus of the colon. But how do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the real xml. For security reasons, I made this up, it looks very much like the real one. The issue is not that it's not well-formed, if it was, I would not be able to select the other attributes either. The issue lies in selecting this kind of attribute   diffgr:hasChanges='modified   (cus of the colon I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the error message

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed.

You need to set a namespace for `diffgr`. Otherwise the expression for the attribute `@diffgr:hasChanges` will not match.

In XSLT you'd add the namespace to the root element

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:diffgr='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1'>
```

In C# with `XmlReader` you can add a namespace like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("diffgr", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1");    
XElement node = root.XPathSelectElement("/*/Data/*/@diffgr:hasChanges", nsmgr);
```

If this doesn't help, try this SO answer: [Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2311526/1305969).

Comment: Another way, easier and better in my case, I found out, that I can do this: 
SelectSingleNode("/*/Data/*/@*[name()='diffgr:hasChanges']");

By using name(), xpath won't look at the namespace, in this case.